# Can I Redirect a user directly on Profile Page in Ionic 3 as soon as it asks for all the required Android permissions?

Tags: ionic3

I am making a hybrid application in Ionic version 3 using Angular 4. I want to know that whether I can redirect the user directly to my Profile Page when the app is opened! Also, it should not stop the functioning of asking run time Android permission which I have asked from the user in my app.component.ts file on app startup!

My **app.component.ts** code:

```
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, NavController, NavParams, Platform, Config } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

    // ===================== pages =====================
    import { CardPage } from '../pages/card/card';
    import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
    import { HistoryPage } from '../pages/history/history';
    import { RequestPage } from '../pages/request/request';
    import { MyCardListPage } from '../pages/my-card-list/my-card-list';
    import { ProfilePage } from '../pages/profile/profile';
    import { PeopleNearbyPage } from '../pages/people-nearby/people-nearby';
    import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    import { AboutUsPage } from '../pages/about-us/about-us';

    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'app.html'
    })
    export class MyApp {
      public lat;
      public long;
      @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
      prof = {
        location: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: []
        }
      };
      user;
      rootPage: any;
      userDetails;
      userId;
      profileDetail;
      // ================== base URL ===============

      URL = "http://localhost:3334/api/";
      image;
      name;
      pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any, image: any }>;
      profile: Array<{ title: string, component: any }>;

      constructor(
        private translate: TranslateService,
        public platform: Platform,
        public statusBar: StatusBar,
        public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
        private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions,
        private geolocation: Geolocation,
        private config: Config,
        private alertCtrl: AlertController,
        public http: Http
      ) {


        this.initTranslate();
        // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
        this.pages = [
          { title: 'Home', component: HomePage, image: "home" },
          { title: 'History', component: HistoryPage, image: "time" },
          { title: 'My Card', component: MyCardListPage, image: "card" },
          { title: 'People Nearby', component: PeopleNearbyPage, image: "people" },
          { title: 'About Us', component: AboutUsPage, image: "information-circle" }
        ];

        this.profile = [{ title: 'ProfilePage', component: ProfilePage }];
        this.initializeApp();
        this.checkLocalStorage();

        //Sunny - Method to Direct a user to profile page if No Profile is Created
        if(this.userDetails == null){
          this.rootPage = ProfilePage;
        }
        else
        {
          this.rootPage = HomePage;
        }

      }


      initTranslate() {
        this.checkLocalStorage()
        // Set the default language for translation strings, and the current language.
        this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
        if (this.translate.getBrowserLang() !== undefined) {
          this.translate.use(this.translate.getBrowserLang());
        } else {
          this.translate.use('en'); // Set your language here
        }
        this.translate.get(['BACK_BUTTON_TEXT']).subscribe(values => {
          this.config.set('ios', 'backButtonText', values.BACK_BUTTON_TEXT);
        });
      }


      initializeApp() {
        this.checkLocalStorage()
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          this.statusBar.styleDefault();
          this.splashScreen.hide();
          this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA).then(
            success => { this.changePos(); this.checkLocalStorage(); },
            err => {
              this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA);
              this.changePos();
              this.checkLocalStorage()
            }
          );
        });
      }

      openPage(page) {
        this.checkLocalStorage();
        this.user = localStorage.getItem('userData');
        if (this.user != undefined || this.user != null) {
          if (this.user.length > 0) {
            if (page.component == MyCardListPage) {
              this.nav.setRoot(page.component, { card: 'mycard', mycardId: this.userId });

            }
            if (page.component == PeopleNearbyPage) {
              this.userDetails = JSON.parse(this.user);
              this.userId = (this.userDetails.id);
              this.nav.setRoot(page.component, { param1: this.userId });
            } else {
              this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
            }
          }

        }
        else {
          this.showAlert();
        }

      }

      showAlert() {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'No Profile Found!',
          subTitle: 'Firstly create a profile!',
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'OK',
              role: 'ok',
              handler: () => {
                 this.openProfilePage()
              }
            }]
        });
        alert.present();
      }

      openProfilePage() {
          this.nav.setRoot(ProfilePage, { param1: this.profileDetail });
        }

      //Function for Changing the lat and long on device startup
      changePos() {
        this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA]);
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
          this.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
          this.long = resp.coords.longitude;

          console.log('lati');
          console.log(this.lat);
          console.log('long');
          console.log(this.long);

          this.prof = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
          if (this.prof.location != null) {
            this.prof.location = null;
            this.prof.location.coordinates.push(this.lat);
            this.prof.location.coordinates.push(this.long);
            localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.prof));
            this.http.patch(this.URL + "Profiles/" + this.userDetails.id, this.prof.location).subscribe(data => {

            });
          }
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error getting location', error);
        });
      }




      // get profile on menu
      checkLocalStorage() {
        console.log('in check local storage');

        let UserDetail = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
        if (UserDetail != null) {
          this.http.get(this.URL + 'Profiles/' + UserDetail.id)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
              this.image = this.getImage(data.profilePicture).toString();
              console.log(this.image);
              this.name = data.firstName;
            });
        }





      }

      getImage(image) {
        return 'url(data:image/jpeg;base64,' + image + ')'
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide your app.component.ts code

Comment: Kindly check the code! I have submitted it in my question.